# Select one field from query with subquery

Tags: mysql

I am using the MySQL query to find distance between tow zip-codes when lat long is given.

```
SELECT postcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 52.47592 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( -1.90539 ) ) + sin( radians( 52.47592 ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM ukpostcodes  HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY distance
```

it is working fine. But I want only postcode in result. I don't want distance column in result .

How can I achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT postcode FROM(
SELECT postcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 52.47592 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( -1.90539 ) ) + sin( radians( 52.47592 ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM ukpostcodes  HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY distance
) AS tbl
```

Comment: Thanks much. But I run this query it is showing this error . Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: @Rich5757: Give a name to the subquery. Something like `as tbl` at the very end of the query.

Comment: Just `tbl`. No need of double quotes.

Comment: @Raging-Bull: True that